# Replace org link description with org link output (shell type)

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I've stored several links to various shell commands and I would like to update each link description with the output of the correspoding shell command. For example:

```
View in text-mode: [[shell:echo "hello"][xxx]]
View in org-mode:  xxx
```

after running some post-processing function, I would get:

```
View in text-mode: [[shell:echo "hello"][hello​]]
View in org-mode:  hello
```

I know how to parse the different links and get the underlying shell command:

```
(org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'link
  (lambda (link)
    (when (string= (org-element-property :type link) "shell")
        (org-element-property :path link))))
```

but then I don't know how to modify the description using `(org-element-context link)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link description is the region in the buffer between the values of the properties `contents-begin` and `contents-end`:

```el
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(defun link-desc-region (link)
   (list (org-element-property :contents-begin link)
         (org-element-property :contents-end link)))

(defun replace-desc-in-link (link newdesc)
   (let ((region (link-desc-region link)))
       (goto-char (nth 0 region))
       (delete-region (nth 0 region) (nth 1 region))
       (insert newdesc))))
#+end_src
```

Evaluating `(replace-desc-in-link (org-element-context) "hello")` with point in the link should do what you want.